# Euro sign in jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, zepto

I'm trying to write a jQuery selector to obtain all `DOMElement` that has a `€` sign in it.
When looking at [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), I would like to write something like:

```
$("*:contains('€')")
```

Unfortunately, I have an

> Uncaught Error: SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12

that shows up in the console log.
I've wonder if it is possible to do it?
I would like to get all the element containing a `€` sign and add a `mouseover` function

Could you help me to figure out what is wrong? I already tried to escape character with `\` or `\\` but it doesn't work.

Here is the code not working:

```
    $("*:contains('€')").each(function () {
        $($(this)).css( "backgroundColor", "blue" );
    });
```

the error on the console log says :

```
Uncaught Error: SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12 zepto.min.js:2
A.qsa zepto.min.js:2
A.init zepto.min.js:2
c zepto.min.js:2
myFunc Script.js:344
```

the line 344 is the line of the code :

```
$("*:contains('€')")
```

Comment: Which browser? Works here tested with chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/VGc2u/

Comment: I also uses chrome  but I still have the error. I will post some code below. I'm using zepto. Is this linked?

Comment: Ok i figured it out!

I was using zepto which is lightweight, but is not Jquery ! (thought it was the same)

Anyway, the code works with Jquery but not with zepto!

Thank you very much, sorry for this error and thanks for your posts!

Comment: Your welcome! I edit your post to include zepto tag, maybe someone knows a workaround

Answer (score 0):

I did a fast test and it works for me.
You might have an error somewhere else in your code, post more of it.
Otherwise try writing: `$("*:contains('&euro;')")` but I don't think that will help.